# docker with .net core app could not build on Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, docker, asp.net-core, azure-devops, devops

Have very interesting issue with building docker on Azure DevOps even don't know how to solve it, didn't find relevant to this error any information, so here is log file with error

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.0.450+ga8dc7f1d34 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
C:\Users\ContainerUser\.nuget\packages\gitinfo\2.0.20\build\GitInfo.targets(905,3): warning MSB3073: The command "git --version" exited with code 9009. [C:\src\Source\TestProject.Web\TestProject.Web.csproj]
  'bash.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
C:\Users\ContainerUser\.nuget\packages\gitinfo\2.0.20\build\GitInfo.targets(924,3): warning MSB3073: The command "C:\Users\ContainerUser\.nuget\packages\gitinfo\2.0.20\build\wslrun.cmd git --version" exited with code 1. [C:\src\Source\TestProject.Web\TestProject.Web.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.602\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.ObsoleteReferences.targets(33,5): warning NETSDK1059: The tool 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet' is now included in the .NET Core SDK. Information on resolving this warning is available at (https://aka.ms/dotnetclitools-in-box). [C:\src\Source\TestProject.Web\TestProject.Web.csproj]
  Restore completed in 377.95 ms for C:\src\Source\TestProject.App.Base.Api\TestProject.App.Base.Api.csproj.
  Restore completed in 377.95 ms for C:\src\Source\TestProject.App.Base.Dto\TestProject.App.Base.Dto.csproj.
  Restore completed in 25.96 ms for C:\src\Source\TestProject.App.Web.Api\TestProject.App.Web.Api.csproj.
  Restore completed in 25.14 ms for C:\src\Source\TestProject.App.Web.Dto\TestProject.App.Web.Dto.csproj.
  Restore completed in 74.95 ms for C:\src\Source\TestProject.App.Base\TestProject.App.Base.csproj.
  Restore completed in 63.88 ms for C:\src\Source\TestProject.App.Web\TestProject.App.Web.csproj.
  Restore completed in 28.04 ms for C:\src\Source\TestProject.Core\TestProject.Core.csproj.
  Restore completed in 4.64 ms for C:\src\Source\TestProject.Data.Model.Common\TestProject.Data.Model.Common.csproj.
  Restore completed in 24.93 ms for C:\src\Source\TestProject.Data.Model\TestProject.Data.Model.csproj.
  Restore completed in 25.5 ms for C:\src\Source\TestProject.Data.Repository\TestProject.Data.Repository.csproj.
  Restore completed in 81.12 ms for C:\src\Source\TestProject.Data.EntityFrameworkCore\TestProject.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.csproj.
  Restore completed in 379.54 ms for C:\src\Source\TestProject.Web\TestProject.Web.csproj.
  'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
C:\Users\ContainerUser\.nuget\packages\gitinfo\2.0.20\build\GitInfo.targets(905,3): warning MSB3073: The command "git --version" exited with code 9009. [C:\src\Source\TestProject.Web\TestProject.Web.csproj]
  'bash.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
C:\Users\ContainerUser\.nuget\packages\gitinfo\2.0.20\build\GitInfo.targets(924,3): warning MSB3073: The command "C:\Users\ContainerUser\.nuget\packages\gitinfo\2.0.20\build\wslrun.cmd git --version" exited with code 1. [C:\src\Source\TestProject.Web\TestProject.Web.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.602\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.ObsoleteReferences.targets(33,5): warning NETSDK1059: The tool 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet' is now included in the .NET Core SDK. Information on resolving this warning is available at (https://aka.ms/dotnetclitools-in-box). [C:\src\Source\TestProject.Web\TestProject.Web.csproj]
  '--version' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
C:\Users\ContainerUser\.nuget\packages\gitinfo\2.0.20\build\GitInfo.targets(152,3): warning MSB3073: The command " --version" exited with code 9009. [C:\src\Source\TestProject.Web\TestProject.Web.csproj]
C:\Users\ContainerUser\.nuget\packages\gitinfo\2.0.20\build\GitInfo.targets(161,3): error : Failed to run `git --version`. Git may not be properly installed:  [C:\src\Source\TestProject.Web\TestProject.Web.csproj]
C:\Users\ContainerUser\.nuget\packages\gitinfo\2.0.20\build\GitInfo.targets(161,3): error :  '--version' is not recognized as an internal or external command,;operable program or batch file. [C:\src\Source\TestProject.Web\TestProject.Web.csproj]

Build FAILED.

C:\Users\ContainerUser\.nuget\packages\gitinfo\2.0.20\build\GitInfo.targets(905,3): warning MSB3073: The command "git --version" exited with code 9009. [C:\src\Source\TestProject.Web\TestProject.Web.csproj]
C:\Users\ContainerUser\.nuget\packages\gitinfo\2.0.20\build\GitInfo.targets(924,3): warning MSB3073: The command "C:\Users\ContainerUser\.nuget\packages\gitinfo\2.0.20\build\wslrun.cmd git --version" exited with code 1. [C:\src\Source\TestProject.Web\TestProject.Web.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.602\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.ObsoleteReferences.targets(33,5): warning NETSDK1059: The tool 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet' is now included in the .NET Core SDK. Information on resolving this warning is available at (https://aka.ms/dotnetclitools-in-box). [C:\src\Source\TestProject.Web\TestProject.Web.csproj]
C:\Users\ContainerUser\.nuget\packages\gitinfo\2.0.20\build\GitInfo.targets(905,3): warning MSB3073: The command "git --version" exited with code 9009. [C:\src\Source\TestProject.Web\TestProject.Web.csproj]
C:\Users\ContainerUser\.nuget\packages\gitinfo\2.0.20\build\GitInfo.targets(924,3): warning MSB3073: The command "C:\Users\ContainerUser\.nuget\packages\gitinfo\2.0.20\build\wslrun.cmd git --version" exited with code 1. [C:\src\Source\TestProject.Web\TestProject.Web.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.602\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.ObsoleteReferences.targets(33,5): warning NETSDK1059: The tool 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet' is now included in the .NET Core SDK. Information on resolving this warning is available at (https://aka.ms/dotnetclitools-in-box). [C:\src\Source\TestProject.Web\TestProject.Web.csproj]
C:\Users\ContainerUser\.nuget\packages\gitinfo\2.0.20\build\GitInfo.targets(152,3): warning MSB3073: The command " --version" exited with code 9009. [C:\src\Source\TestProject.Web\TestProject.Web.csproj]
C:\Users\ContainerUser\.nuget\packages\gitinfo\2.0.20\build\GitInfo.targets(161,3): error : Failed to run `git --version`. Git may not be properly installed:  [C:\src\Source\TestProject.Web\TestProject.Web.csproj]
C:\Users\ContainerUser\.nuget\packages\gitinfo\2.0.20\build\GitInfo.targets(161,3): error :  '--version' is not recognized as an internal or external command,;operable program or batch file. [C:\src\Source\TestProject.Web\TestProject.Web.csproj]
    7 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:04.41
The command 'cmd /S /C dotnet build "TestProject.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app' returned a non-zero code: 1
##[error]C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe failed with return code: 1
##[section]Finishing: Build an image
```

On my windows machine it builds fine without any errors occurred. I tried different agent pools in Azure DevOps but have same issues. Could someone tell me what is here going on

Also if needed here is my dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Development"

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Source/TestProject.Web/TestProject.Web.csproj", "Source/TestProject.Web/"]
COPY ["Source/TestProject.Data.EntityFrameworkCore/TestProject.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.csproj", "Source/TestProject.Data.EntityFrameworkCore/"]
COPY ["Source/TestProject.Core/TestProject.Core.csproj", "Source/TestProject.Core/"]
COPY ["Source/TestProject.App.Base.Dto/TestProject.App.Base.Dto.csproj", "Source/TestProject.App.Base.Dto/"]
COPY ["Source/TestProject.Data.Model/TestProject.Data.Model.csproj", "Source/TestProject.Data.Model/"]
COPY ["Source/TestProject.Data.Model.Common/TestProject.Data.Model.Common.csproj", "Source/TestProject.Data.Model.Common/"]
COPY ["Source/TestProject.Data.Repository/TestProject.Data.Repository.csproj", "Source/TestProject.Data.Repository/"]
COPY ["Source/TestProject.App.Web.Dto/TestProject.App.Web.Dto.csproj", "Source/TestProject.App.Web.Dto/"]
COPY ["Source/TestProject.App.Web/TestProject.App.Web.csproj", "Source/TestProject.App.Web/"]
COPY ["Source/TestProject.App.Base.Api/TestProject.App.Base.Api.csproj", "Source/TestProject.App.Base.Api/"]
COPY ["Source/TestProject.App.Web.Api/TestProject.App.Web.Api.csproj", "Source/TestProject.App.Web.Api/"]
COPY ["Source/TestProject.App.Base/TestProject.App.Base.csproj", "Source/TestProject.App.Base/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Source/TestProject.Web/TestProject.Web.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Source/TestProject.Web"
RUN dotnet build "TestProject.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TestProject.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestProject.Web.dll"]
```

Does somebody faced this issue?

Comment: I believe it has been discussed on GitHub https://github.com/kzu/GitInfo/issues This package depends on local Git client, which you didn't seem to have installed as part of your Dockerfile.